# Flutter firebase onBackgroundMessage throws exception

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

When i add this function to my code.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(
        (message) => _handleBG(message, currentUserId));
```

I get exception

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toRawHandle' was called on null.
```

onMessage method below is working fine.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) async {
          //  event.messageType
          print('hearing to  foreground messsage');
          if (event.data['messageType'] == 'chat') {
            await ChatHelper.handleMessageReceived(event, context, currentUserId);
            //setState(() {});
    
          }
        });
    
        FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(
            (message) => _handleBG(message, currentUserId));
```

Answer (score 0):

The background message handler should be declared as a top-level function so that it can be called independently, as you never know the state of your app and its object when the notification is received. It looks like that your `_handleBG` method is a private method available to a specific class only.

From code documentation

```
/// This provided handler must be a top-level function and cannot be
/// anonymous otherwise an [ArgumentError] will be thrown.
```